# linked to non existing shared library in Cmake

Tags: c, linker, cmake, ld

I have a CMAKE project, and I am using pcap. in my cmake file I have the following:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib pcap)
```

and installed on my system i have the following

in /usr/lib

```
/usr/lib/libpcap.so -> /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so
```

in /usr/local/lib

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.3.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so -> /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.3.0
```

yet when I build my code, and run ldd on the executable, I get

```
libpcap.so.1 => not found
```

so the question is where is the reference to libpcap.so.1 coming from, and how can i fix it? Whether it be changing something in my cmake setup, or on the system.

edit: I did a find on my system, and libpcap.so.1 is definitely nowhere else on the system either

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this issue may be the following:

1. Set `PCAP_LIBRARIES` to the list of libraries you want to link (I suggest absolute path)
2. Set `PCAP_LIBRARIES_DIR` to a column separated list of directories where the libraries reside
3. Set the libraries you want to link

   `target_link_libraries( mylib ${PCAP_LIBRARIES} )`
4. Set target properties accordingly

   `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( myexe
     PROPERTIES
     INSTALL_RPATH ${PCAP_LIBRARIES_DIR}
   )`